# Calculate average sales using criteria from one dataframe and aggregating in other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have `df1$NextBizDay` which has dates.
Other dataframe `df2` has two columns `df2$Date` and `df2$Sales`

Now I am trying to calculate average sales using dates from `df1$NextBizDay`. As `df1$NextBizDay` can have duplicate dates I calculated the frequency of each date using `as.data.frame(table(df1$NextBizDay))[,2]`

Now I need to sum and divide so that I can get average sales.

I know `aggregate(Sales~Date,df2,sum)[,2]` will give me total sales for each date but I am not sure how to proceed further.

> Example input:

```
    df1$NextBizday  
    2018-10-22  
    2018-10-22  
    2018-10-23  
    2018-10-23  
    2018-10-23  
    2018-10-24  


    df2$Date    df2$Sales
    2018-10-22  1000
    2018-10-23  2000
    2018-10-24  3000
    2018-10-25  4000
    2018-10-26  5000
    2018-10-27  6000
```

> Expected output   df1

```
    NextBizday AvgSales
    2018-10-22  500
    2018-10-22  500
    2018-10-23  666.6666667
    2018-10-23  666.6666667
    2018-10-23  666.6666667
    2018-10-24  3000
```

basically what I am trying to do is lookup each date from df1 in df2 and divide sales by the frequency of date in df1.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `data.table` join between the two datasets `on` the 'NextBizday/Date' column and then do the assignment (`:=`) by taking the `sum` of 'Sales' and dividing with the number of rows (`.N`) to create the 'AvgSales'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, AvgSales := sum(Sales)/.N, on = .(NextBizday = Date), by = .EACHI]
df1
#   NextBizday  AvgSales
#1: 2018-10-22  500.0000
#2: 2018-10-22  500.0000
#3: 2018-10-23  666.6667
#4: 2018-10-23  666.6667
#5: 2018-10-23  666.6667
#6: 2018-10-24 3000.0000
```

---

Another option is `tidyverse`, which may be a bit more easier to understand

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  # do a left join
  left_join(df2, by = c("NextBizday" = "Date")) %>%
  # grouped by NextBizday
  group_by(NextBizday) %>% 
  # divide the `first` value of 'Sales' by the number of rows `n()`
  transmute(AvgSales = first(Sales)/n())
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   NextBizday [3]
#  NextBizday AvgSales
#  <date>        <dbl>
#1 2018-10-22     500 
#2 2018-10-22     500 
#3 2018-10-23     667.
#4 2018-10-23     667.
#5 2018-10-23     667.
#6 2018-10-24    3000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(NextBizday = structure(c(17826, 17826, 17827, 
17827, 17827, 17828), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17826, 17827, 17828, 17829, 
17830, 17831), class = "Date"), Sales = c(1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 
4000L, 5000L, 6000L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Sales~Date, df2, FUN = mean, na.rm = T)[,2]
```

Comment: I initially tried this but the thing is dates are duplicates in df1 only not in df2.